# why my app deals with array from backend a string?

Tags: php, angular, laravel, typescript, ionic-framework

I have stored a column as an array but when I received this from server in ionic, ionic will deal with it as a string and not array

this is how it's stored

```
["loca6_1.jpeg","loca6_1.jpeg"]
```

here is the backend function and it is written in php laravel

```
return Auth::user()->attachments()->pluck('filename');
```

and database we're using phpMyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the column to an array:

**Attachment.php**

```
protected $casts = [
    'filename' => 'array',
];
```

This is untested, but I think you'd need to do something like this to merge all the individual arrays in to one.

```
return Auth::user()->attachments()->pluck('filename')->flatten();
```